# WebRTC app on IOS not working on US iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I built an iOS video call app in Swift. It works in tests with my colleagues in India and Morocco. I'm in Morocco. The app doesn't work on any iPhones of my colleagues in the U.S.. Like us they have the latest iOS and iPhones 7 and 8. None worked. The video call doesn't connect and I'm receiving the socket connection as I keep checking my logs.

I searched everywhere and tried some solutions, but none worked for me. What I did is:
• Transport protocol, checked and activated to allow all sockets
Reduced the video quality (I suspected it may be a network issue)

This issue is present only with US iPhones. For a video call app like this, is there any difference between iPhones in U.S. versus in Morocco and India? Is it a Security issue? Maybe Apple is blocking our connection as being suspicious?

Techs & Libraries:

Skylink SDK
OneSignal SDK
Swift

Detail of our American colleagues phones: 
• OS: ios 11.3.1
• wifi download 96 mbps
• wifi upload 11.7 mbps
• Devices = iphone 8 and iphone X.
• ISP: spectrum internet

I haven't included any codes as per the application works fine in our side.

Comment: let me know if anyone needs a piece of code.

Comment: Try a VPN - I suspect the problem is with your service provider in the US. Also check with other implementations of WebRTC and appRTC, there are some working such as https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios

Comment: thanks for your comment, after a while we switched to another SDK called OpenTOK and it worked, I am suspecting the old one has an issue of latency maybe, they refused to answer our questions of where their servers are deployed and how their architecture is working to deliver sockets, so we changed to openTOK and it worked, thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you look this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783635/how-to-integrate-webrtc-video-calling-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED BY CHANGING THE SDK**

It turned out that the issue was coming from Skylink servers being deployed in Singapore, this lead to a big latency between the peer and the server, and it never transfer the video content.

After switching to something inside USA (OpenTOK) the application started working fine.